# IntelliSense in Tuple types

Tags: typescript, types, tuples, intellisense

Is it possible to have autocomplete working on the content of a Tuple type? And also why it's not possible with a "simple" type as shown in next example;

```js
type Litterals = 'foo' | 'bar';

type T1<T extends Litterals> = T;
// good autocomplete on simple literal
type Test1 = T1<'bar'>;

type T2<T extends Litterals[]> = T;
// no autocomplete
type Test2 = T2<['']>

type TBonus<...(T extends Litterals)> = T;
// how to achieve that?
type TestBonus = TBonus<'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo' /* ... and as much as we want */>
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=85#code/C4TwDgpgBAMglsYEBOBDANgZygXigcgDMB7Y-KAHwICNVl8BuAKCdEigBUBGAHg6ggAPJADsAJtniIUGTAD5cnZgHplUAOakxUVAFdgxAMbEAtmHQQkUYiKiY4Zi1HQIZ6VuGgcImYF0XcPPi09HLMHuwcAEx8AsIQ4pIISGhYANoAugp4HCpqIsQ6+kam5pYQEV4+wFEBMWn4+FksbF4AQja6mDwAdH0AFPxCohKwyW6YAJTZSkyqUAAWxADuUAY6hgtwEABu0MALqMAA-JWc1R0iXQGXXUEkZAA0NHT4z8Gv7w-kygBUUH0ejpxDpsCZdJtQVBltBlqgRMAoL9lHIgA)

Comment: Variadic type aliases don't exist yet, the autocomplete is probably a feature request...

Comment: Don't know if it's a matter of feature. This looks either like a bug or a missunderstanding on my side.

If you talk about my `TBonus` type, yes, obviously this is a feature